# How to set relative position with Grandfather! element?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a layout like this:

```
<div class='one'>
   <div class='two'>
       <div class='three'>some text</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is possible to set relative position for three according to grandfather element (`one`) in CSS?

Look this:
http://jsfiddle.net/chalist/H48Je/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an element has `position: relative` and you move it (say `left: 20px`) it moves in relation to its natural position in the flow of the page, leaving a gap where it was before (which no other element will grab, as it were). So in a way, the simple answer is yes: if you give `.three` a relative position and move it, it will move in relation to all its ancestors.

Generally, though, if you want to move an element in relation to an ancestor, you'd normally give the ancestor `position: relative` and the element that's being moved `position: absolute`. Then any positioning (e.g. `top: 20px`) will be in relation to the positioned ancestor, and the element being moved won't leave a gap behind.

The one thing to note is that this positioning will be in relation to the nearest positioned ancestor. So if `.two` has positioning, you won't be able to position `.three` in relation to `.one` ... (not directly, anyway).

BTW, if an element is set to `position: absolute` and no ancestor has any positioning set, any co-ordinates set on the absolute element will be in relation to the viewport.